# wanted to know i have a log with 2 different grok pattern... i wanted to put that in IF statement

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

i have 2 patterns in one log and i wanted to put that in the grok pattern with if statement

```
1.%{LOGLEVEL:log} \[%{DATA:class}\] %{NOTSPACE:Property} %{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE} %{NOTSPACE} (?<id>[^ ]*) %{NOTSPACE} %{NOTSPACE} %{IPORHOST:ip}


2.%{LOGLEVEL:log} \[%{DATA:class}\] %{NOTSPACE:Property}:\ %{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE} %{DATA:symbol},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{DATA:buyBrokerId},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{DATA:price},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{DATA:buyFee},%{SPACE} %{DATA:sellFee},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if [type] == "" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => ["%{LOGLEVEL:log} \[%{DATA:class}\] %{NOTSPACE:Property} %{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE} %{NOTSPACE} (?<id>[^ ]*) %{NOTSPACE} %{NOTSPACE} %{IPORHOST:ip}" , "%{LOGLEVEL:log} \[%{DATA:class}\] %{NOTSPACE:Property}:\ %{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE} %{DATA:symbol},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{DATA:buyBrokerId},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{DATA:price},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE},%{SPACE} %{DATA:buyFee},%{SPACE} %{DATA:sellFee},"] }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you i am new to this @angel... what i should put in TYPE part and in the string (" ") part.... please let me knw

Comment: input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter{
mutate{
gsub => ["message", "\:", " "]
}

if[type] == ""
{
grok{
match => { "message" => "%{LOGLEVEL:log} \[%{DATA:class}\] %{NOTSPACE:Property} %{SPACE} %{NOTSPACE} %{NOTSPACE} (?<id>[^ ]*) %{NOTSPACE} %{NOTSPACE} %{IPORHOST:ip}"}
}
}
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}

Comment: in the type part if i try  if[LOGLEVEL] == "INFO"... it is not working

Comment: @karthiksl17 Edit your question instead of using comments to add information.